# Eclipse shortcuts confirmation

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

So i have the following problem: Every time i use any of the Eclipse Shortcuts(I'm using Eclipse Luna) i get this weird small rectangle in the bottom right of my screen with the shortcut i have pressed and the action that it does and i need to press enter in order to do that particular action. Needless to say this is extremely bothersome.

I cannot put a print screen as every time i press the fn button on the laptop it disappears.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this "notification"?

Comment: Do they occour even if eclipse is not running?

Comment: Have you tried to restore the default settings? See: http://abload.de/img/screenjfou7.png

Comment: This sounds like the shortcut conflict prompt which is normally shown when there are two or more actions bound to the same key.

Comment: What keys in what order for example?